# Paypal Update Notification URL Or Use Dynamic URL

Tags: javascript, paypal, paypal-ipn

I want to trigger an `ipn.php` file once someone uses the Paypal Smart Button. I've tried updating the Notification URL in my account but the value won't update and it still uses the old url which no longer works, despite showing that I've change the URL in the input field.

I've tried to do a dynamic aproach with `notify_url` like this:

```
paypal.Buttons({
    style : {
        shape: 'rect',
        color: 'gold',
        layout: 'vertical',
        label: 'paypal',
    },
    createOrder : (data, actions) => {
        return actions.order.create({
            purchase_units: [{
                description : Payment.description,
                custom_id: Payment.description,
                amount : {
                    currency_code: "USD",
                    value: Payment.amount
                },
                notify_url: 'https://www.my-new-url.com/ipn.php'
            }],
            application_context: {
                shipping_preference : 'NO_SHIPPING'
            }
        })
    },
    onApprove : (data, actions) => {
        return actions.order.capture().then(function(orderData) {
            console.log('Capture result', orderData, JSON.stringify(orderData, null, 2))
        })
    },
    onError : (err) => {
        console.log(err)
    }
}).render('#paypal-button-container')
```

However it still did not work. Am I using `notify_url` wrong? How can I make this work?

I'd like to either know how I can force the Notification URL to update in my account or how to use the `notify_url` parameter in order to set the Notification URL dynamically, either is fine. Any ideas how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parameters you can use are the same as those documented for the [Create Order](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/orders/v2/#orders_create) API call .. `notify_url` (or equivalent) is not one of them, because IPN is very old and should be deprecated. Why are you using it with a new integration of a PayPal JS SDK button?

In general there is no reason to wait for asynchronous notifications. You can get an immediate, synchronous notification of completed payments by combining the JS SDK for approval with a backend for order creation and capture.

Use the v2/checkout/orders API and make two routes (url paths) on your server, one for 'Create Order' and one for 'Capture Order'. You could use one of the (recently deprecated) Checkout-*-SDKs for the routes' API calls to PayPal, or your own HTTPS implementation of first getting an access token and then doing the call. Both of these routes should return/output **only** JSON data (no HTML or text). Inside the 2nd route, when the capture API is successful you should verify the amount was correct and store its resulting payment details in your database (particularly `purchase_units[0].payments.captures[0].id`, which is the PayPal transaction ID) and perform any necessary business logic (such as reserving product or sending an email) immediately *before* forwarding return JSON to the frontend caller. In the event of an error forward the JSON details of it as well, since the frontend must handle such cases.

Pair those 2 routes with this frontend approval flow: https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server .  (If you need to send any additional data from the client to the server, such as an items array or selected options, add a `body` parameter to the fetch with a value that is a JSON string or object)

---

If for some reason you actually need an asynchronous, after-the-fact notification of payment completion (unclear why you would need it), Webhooks are the newer replacement to IPN.

Comment: Webhook Notification seems to be the way to go. As a matter of fact I need `asynchronous, after-the-fact notification of payment completion` and this is just what I was looking for. Thanks for your help!

Comment: You haven't said why you need it, so I have to remain skeptical; integrations that wait for asynchronous postbacks are more likely to break or have unforseen delays. In general the vast majority of ecommerce is best served with the immediate synchronous capture response, but again we don't have details about why this wouldn't be the case for what you're doing so I just want to emphasize that for most people reading this webhooks are *not* the way to go.

Comment: If you need to have an `asynchronous after-the-fact notification of payment completion` webhooks is exactly what you should use though. You cannot use IPN they really do not support that anymore. I've already implemented webhooks in my system and it works great.

Comment: Waiting for a postback from the webhook service is an extra dependency and point of failure, subject to potential delays and errors. You haven't explained why you need it, vs. the immediate (synchronous) capture response. The vast majority of API-based integrations should *not* use webhooks for normal payment notifications as they are not needed and depending on them is less reliable.

Comment: I'm not using the webhook service for simply `capture response`, you're right that would not be practical. In my case suffice it to say that the delay you mentioned plays a curcial role and is absolutely expected and necessary.